# Change colour of Shape in JavaFX controller

Tags: javafx, controller, hide, visibility

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm trying to set a shape to be invisible or at least change the colour of the shape so it's not visible. Since I need to be able to change the visibility, I can't set this in the FXML file, so I have been trying to do this in the Class controller so far I have tried to set the visibility and the colour and both times it throws an exception, I don't know what is causing the problem.

```
@FXML
private Rectangle shape1;

@FXML
private void genrateResults(){
    shape1.setVisible(false);
}

@FXML
private void genrateResults(){
    final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorPicker.setValue(Color.WHITE);

    shape1.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
    shape1.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());;
}

<Rectangle id="shape1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="18.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="44.0" />
```

And the exception thrown

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$153/1840143265.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Unknown Source)
at application.MenuController.ShowDashBoard(MenuController.java:95)
at application.MenuController.HandleDashBoardView(MenuController.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$153/1840143265.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 115 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.DashboardController.genrateResults(DashboardController.java:56)
... 124 more
```

Both of these did not work. I suspect it might not be possible to change these details in the controller, also the fill and stroke is described in the FXML file could this be causing an issue as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Did the JVM really crash, or did your Java code just throw an exception? If it's an exception, please post the stack trace (edit your question to include it). It would probably help to also include your FXML file (at least the portions relevant to the question).

Comment: it throw an exception,

Comment: OK, can you post the stack trace from the exception in your question? And also identify which line in the code you posted corresponds to the line where the exception is generated.

Comment: Hi, just posted the stack trace for the exception. It's on line 56, I only showed the part of the code which was causing problems. If I run the program without the set fill and set stroke it works fine so its's those two lines which generate the exception.

Comment: You used `id="shape1"` in the FXML, instead of `fx:id="shape1"`. Consequently `shape1` is not initialized in the controller, and you get the `NullPointerException`.